# Change the text color of a list generated by ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, textcolor

I am fairly new to Android. I am looking to change the text color of a list, nested within a navigation drawer. I have a resource file with a string-array and 5 items. I then populate the navigation drawer using an ArrayAdapter but I created the "menu" as a ListView. ListView does not have a textColor property that I can set. How can I change the ListView text color?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] menuItemsForDrawer;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView gpsJobcardDrawerList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menuItemsForDrawer = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gps_jobcard_menu_items);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        gpsJobcardDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        gpsJobcardDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItemsForDrawer));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Main Content View (Must be first child in the DrawerLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_grey_color"/>
    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_color" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

gps_jobcard_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="gps_jobcard_menu_items">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: You need to create a custom resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current resource `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` you are using is an android resource. If you need to change its look and feel then you should create your own resource and use it. This is how we do it.

Create an xml layout say `navigation_item.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#25383C" <!-- any color you need -->
/>
```

and change

```
gpsJobcardDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItemsForDrawer));
```

to

```
gpsJobcardDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.navigation_item, menuItemsForDrawer));
```

Comment: @OwenNel:  Great! You can accept this as answer then. :D

Answer (score 0):

don't use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` make your own custom layout

**layout_simple_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8.0dip"
    android:text="Text"
     android:textColor=""
    android:textSize="20.0sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
 gpsJobcardDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_simple_list_item, menuItemsForDrawer));
```

Comment: If you add any node except of a `TextView` to in the resouce you are using inside an `ArrayAdapter` you would face error `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` unless you create a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

This is a android system layout , I guess you can edit the color of the text by extracting the TextView by reflection and then setting the parameters for the same.